# Google Maps tracks API

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, gps, tracking

I need help: I am developing an application with use Google Maps tracks API. I am not able to use the Google Maps tracks API. I am using [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/tracks/?hl=pt-br).

In the documentation there's:

***Request and response format**

The API accepts requests and returns responses in JavaScript Object Notation (JSON) format.
All requests are made using HTTP POST requests.

**Base path**

The API's base path is: https://www.googleapis.com/tracks/v1/path/to/method*

How do I import the map using Google Maps tracks API? Or how do I to show a map using Google Maps tracks API?

For example using Google Maps API v3 this code works:

```
src = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=myKey&sensor=true';
```

I thought the code below is correct but doesn't work.

```
src = 'https://www.googleapis.com/tracks/v1/path/to/method?key=myKey&sensor=true';
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: the base path is worked ? i have also working on this api but  i m confusing its open or not for public